# How to recover worksheet password from .xlsb excel file

Tags: excel, passwords

I was working on a project. I had to password my sheets but now excel is not accepting the password (even though I think the password I supplied is correct, not sure though). Please, how can I recover my password? I've tried converting to .zip file format, but since it's a binary workbook (.xlsb), I only saw only .bin files in the xl folder instead of the .xml format as in the case of .xlsx. Please help!

Comment: If you search you will find VBA code that can remove sheet protection and you can set your own password.

Comment: VBA to remove sheet protection? Without password? To unprotect a passworded sheet using `ActiveSheet.Unprotect ` even requires the password.

Comment: take it or leave it. There is code that can unprotect password protected sheets. It uses an algorithm that does not require the exact password, so you will never learn what that password used to be. It just unprotects the protected sheet. Search for that and you will find. Note that Excel password sheet protection is not a security feature, because it is so easy to crack it.

Comment: @teylyn I think I got the code you talked about and tested it with a new workbook but still didn't work. It's been up to 3½ hrs now and the excel workbook is not responding at all. The thing is, I used a passphrase (not just an ordinary password) and it's up to 18 characters long (not 12). My only saving grace to recovering that file was my recycle ♻️  bin which contained a previous version of the file.